# Мультитач-масштабирование при помощи Unity Canvas

Tags: canvas, unity3d, масштабирование

Добрый день, коллеги! Кто-нибудь может посоветовать, можно ли каким-то простым способом масштабировать изображение на экране планшета средствами Canvas/EventSystem Unity - пусть пользователь масштабирует изображение при помощи двух пальцев на тачскрине?

Answer (score 3):

как пример, можешь попробовать поставить канвас скейлер в режим Match Width or Height
там ползунок поставить на 50.

а с помощью скрипта который отлавливает нужный жест изменять параметры базового размера экрана того же канвас скейлера.

Должно выйти то что тебе нужно.

Или же придумать что подобное для других режимов канвас скейлера.